# HTML/CSS: Making width consistent across multiple resolutions

Tags: html, css, resolution

I have some squares s of size 15px rendered on a page. Their absolute size varies based on the screen resolution - so on very large resolutions, these end up looking much smaller than I want them to be.

How do I define the width in CSS to make sure they are more or less proportionate across all the different resolutions?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use percentages.

```
  width:20%
```

this way the width is a percentage of the screen size regardless of resolution.

Answer (score 0):

Read about [**CSS Units**](http://www.w3schools.com/css/css_units.asp). You need to use relative unit, such as: `em` or `ex`. Percentage is always a good way to go, but sometimes it’s hard to 'bind it' to the font size.